# Flutter Build Failed due to Mutlidex Error

Tags: android-multidex, flutter-dependencies

This is the Error which i recieved when i tried to Run the Flutter Application.

1. Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex 
   list.# methods: 67061 > 65536.
2. The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k.

Then i Updated build.gradle as "multiDexEnabled true ". But then i
recieved different Error.

1. Could not find method multiDexEnabled() for arguments [true] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the dependency in order to enable multidex.
Open project/app/build.gradle and add:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```